# Meaning of "a quick take"

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does "a quick take" mean in the following context?
Especially the usage of"take".

"As a writer who has produced award-winning novels, novellas, short stories and essays, Chabon has done a stellar job of picking not only the right ideas, but ones with variety. He has also learned which should occupy a lot of his time and which are better suited to **a quick take.**"

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

"**A quick take**" in this sentence means a brief review of the aforementioned ideas.

This definition becomes clearer when you analyze the context in which it appears:

"...which [ideas] should occupy a lot of his time..."

is contrasted with

"...which [ideas] are better suited to **a quick take**."

He will spend considerable time reviewing or thinking about some ideas, and others he will only review or think about briefly.

In English, the noun **take** has varied meanings, in this case:

[a distinct or personal point of view, outlook, or assessment](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take)